# What should I use to preload data using Volley on Android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-volley, synchronous

I have some data stored in a database. In this case the users of an application.

I want to retrieve all their information and put on a layout of my application so I need that the data will be retrieved at `onCreate` function of my layout class to display on it when you change to that layout.

I know about `AsyncTask` and `Volley` to do asynchronous requests to my API but it makes that most times not whole users will be displayed on the layout because they had not been retrieved yet at the moment that the layout is rendered.

I also have searched and it seems that there are some ways (that sometimes seems workarounds) to make both `AsyncTask` and `Volley` synchronous but they block the UIThread.

I know the difference about the `asynchronous` and `synchronous` requests and why the second one blocks the application so I have some questions.

- Is it always recommended to use asynchronous requests?
- If synchronous requests are bad, what is used in those cases in which you need that the data that you retrieve from your database will be displayed at the same time the layout is rendered?
- If I want that those data will be available on the whole class of the layout, how can I handle it? I need to display the data on the screen when the layout is rendered but I also want to make some stuff with it so if I try to use it in any place out of `onResponse` method of Volley request I always get `null`. Something as a "preload" of the data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to delay rendering your layout until the data is loaded. You can set your layout, show a ProgressDialog or something along those lines until the async request has completed, then populate your layout.

Comment: @nicobatu And if I want to use these data to work with it in the same layout, should I use global variables? I mean, to access to the data that has been retrieved for example in an onClick function of a button that is on the same layout.

Comment: The API request completed callback should be calling some method to update your UI. It can pass the data as a parameter.

Comment: @nicobatu So should I reload the layout one time the data has been retrieved?

Comment: You can show a loading dialog while the data is still being retrieved/updated.

Comment: @nicobatu Yes, I know about it but the problem that I am facing or at least that I am asking is about how it is usually done when you need that some data of Volley will be preloaded to use it on the whole class of the layout. Or should I make all the future calcs or whatever in which I need this data inside `onResponse` method of `Volley` request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I notice that my problem was about concepts because I thought that you would not be able to use the data retrieved out from `onResponse` method of `Volley` request.

Finally what I did is to create a global variable on my Fragment and assign the data to that variable when it is fully retrieved. Lets say that I have a String that I want to retrieve.

Then I create the global variable (on the top of the Fragment):

```
String string = "";
```

And I create a function that will assign a parameter to this global variable:

```
public void setString(String string){
    this.string = string;
}
```

To end, after I retrieve the String I call to that function on `onResponse` method:

```
StringRequest jsonArrayRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
           //Do stuff to retrieve the String
           setString(response); //Assign the string "response" to the global variable via the method.
        } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         Log.e("LOG", error.toString());
    }
});
```

If you need to do some stuff with those data you should wait until the data is fully retrieved so you can show a Dialog in the meantime.

I do not know if there is a better way to do this or if this is a bad practice but it is the simplest way I could find by myself.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it always recommended to use asynchronous requests?

It is not only recommended, but essentially the only way to make a request, as Android will not allow for you to make a request on the UI thread.

Everything runs on the main ui thread, unless you otherwise specify. So when you make a request to a server, unless you put that on another thread it will throw an exception.

> If synchronous requests are bad, what is used in those cases in which you need that the data that you retrieve from your database will be displayed at the same time the layout is rendered

Most of the time it is a good idea to pay the cost of loading the data, and caching it on page load, the first time so that you don't have to keep making this call down the road. Keep in mind, it is also not a great idea to load all the user's data at once, as this isn't scalable with large amounts of data. You will likely want to paginate this data so that it loads, say, 25 pieces of data at a time, caches it, and when you need the next page you can go and fetch it.

You may run into some people referring to runOnUiThread methods that essentially run the code you want on the UI thread. I don't recommend you do this, especially when you are loading a data of the size you probably are looking to do.

So to give you somewhere to start, research a little on the following topics.

1. Caching (local storage i.e. [Realm](https://github.com/realm))
2. Handling paging (pagination [article](https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b#.5vi7rj9ek))
3. Try to avoid using async tasks, they are hard to handle and more headache than they're worth. Look into [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)
4. Understand how the Android framework works and the differences between synchronous and asynchronous paradigms.

Comment: And what should I do if I need all the data at the same time? For example, I need to make the average of all marks of all users also and I would like that this value will be in the main page. I like the idea of paginating the rest of users but I would like to show also general values on the main page when loading the layout.

Comment: @Error404 you can put an indicator on your layout, like a progress dialog, that shows the user that you are waiting for that chunk of data to appear. It will block the UI until that data is visible. Now if you are talking real time data, i.e. updating values in real time, then that is a separate task and I can refer you on how to do that.

Comment: I am sorry but maybe we are talking about the same and I am not explaining myself very well. I need that some values will be displayed on the layout, and they will be static on it. Another values will be stored static but I have to use them for different purposes. For example, imagine that I preload all the marks of all the users (`onCreate` function of my layout) but I want to make some calcs with them and display on the screen or manipulate these marks. The problem I am having is that I always get null values well I try to make some calcs with those marks because they are asynchronous.

Comment: And for example if I press one Button the marks are truncated so should I also add the onclick handler on the onResponse of Volley request?

Comment: Are you calling notifydatasetchanged on your adapter after you get these new values?

Comment: I think I know where I got confused. I will try it and post an answer if I finally have it. But I think that `notifydatasetchanged` is not neccesary in this case. I will update at any change.

Answer (score 0):

please have a try with PreLoader: https://github.com/luckybilly/PreLoader

pre-load data with Volley before Activity launched, and retrieve data after UI initialization at Activity.onCreate() with preLoaderId.